# How do i connect a servlet to android app using URLconnection.?

Tags: java, android, servlets, android-studio

I am developing an Andriod app to access database using java-servlet.
As I'm using sdk 23 some previous modules are deprecated, so I'm using URLconnection class to get connection to servlet.
But By running below code, my app stops working.

App is built upon Navigation drawer activity and below code is implemented in one fragment class. And yes I've set permissions for network

```
package com.example.nirmal.gaminghub;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.Object;

public class GameList extends Fragment {


TextView gm_lst=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.game_list);
Button show;
String str ="" ;

public GameList() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                URL openUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/GamingHub/ShowDataServlet");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) openUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder getOutput = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    getOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
                str=line;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return str;
        }

        protected void OnPostExecute(String otpt)
        {
            gm_lst.setText(otpt);
        }
    }.execute();
    gm_lst.setText(str);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_list, container, false);
   }
 }
```

Below code is for servlet, which is working perfectly.

```
package com.gaming_hub;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


 public class ShowDataServlet extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gaming_hub","root","");
        String sql="SELECT * from games";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

       // DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowDataServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowDataServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowDataServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowDataServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: What do you mean it stops working?

Comment: Like, we get a pop up that Unfortunately, your app has stopped working

Comment: If this happens, there will be a stack trace in the debug console. That information is critical to determining where the problem originates from.

Comment: Ok then what should I do.? @ChristopherSchneider

Comment: Run the app in debug mode. Follow Google's documentation on how to do this: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: Link which you have given is not opening. I shouldn't ask but can you give me reference how to use AsyncTask easily to connect servlet with android app.? @ChristopherSchneider

Comment: Thank with an upvote :-)

Comment: what about reference i asked?Are you willing to give it to me.? @ChristopherSchneider

Comment: That link definitely works, and the truth is, if you don't know how to debug your application the odds of getting it to work are next to nil. For all I know, your code works perfectly and you're using the wrong URL (Which is likely, considering it's localhost). In short, you don't even know what your problem is.

Comment: No. URL connection successfully deploying on localhost. There is something wrong after connection which I don't know since I am new at AsyncTask. Even, I couldn't put a toast in AsyncTask to check error.@ChristopherSchneider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace would probably clearly point out that the problem is with the code line:

```
TextView gm_lst=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.game_list);
```

The problem has to do with the `Fragment` lifecycle. You just can't (succesfully) call `findViewById()` at that point as the `Fragment` and its views don't really exist yet.

For example the `onViewCreated()` method would be a safe place to call `findViewById()`. So you could try something like:

```
public class GameList extends Fragment {


TextView gm_lst;
Button show;
String str ="" ;

public GameList() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_list, container, false);
   }
 }

 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    gm_lst = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.game_list);

    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                URL openUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/GamingHub/ShowDataServlet");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) openUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder getOutput = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    getOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
                str=line;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return str;
        }

        protected void OnPostExecute(String otpt)
        {
            gm_lst.setText(otpt);
        }
    }.execute();
    gm_lst.setText(str);

    }
```

And then a separate issue is that you assign `str = line;` and only get what the last `br.readLine()` returned when you probably want the contents of the `getOutput`.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer, but I tried that too but couldn't connect.@MarkusKauppinen